# The Wife's divorce rights in Jewish Law

Tags: halacha, divorce, aguna

Halacha dictates that a man must hand the Get out of free will to his wife for a divorce to take effect.

If the man is mentally unstable, in a full time coma, a sadistic individual or his whereabouts are unknown the wife is essentially chained.

Is there anyway to circumvent this problem?

Recently read a case of Tzefat Bet Din granting a Get on behalf of a terminally comatose husband. I know the ruling is under scrutiny now by the Rabbinate. I don't know the details but it's a pretty well known case.

Source - http://blogs.timesofisrael.com/replacing-the-torah-with-chaos-the-chief-rabbi-seeks-to-undo-a-divorce/

Comment: regarding the Tzefat case, consider http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38515/759

Comment: Knowing what we know about the division of labor throughout most of human history, before the dawn of modernity, would you think it probable or plausible that an average woman would even want to consider divorcing her main source of income, thereby inadvertently condemning herself to an exceedingly undesirable way of life ?